# My program keeps giving me points even if I give the wrong answer

Tags: python

My program keeps letting me continue forever even if I don't get it right except if I put in a number larger than 3.

You'll see what I mean if you try out my code:

```
#Ghost Game

while True:

    print ('Welcome To...') 
    from random import randint
    print ('Ghost Game') 
    feeling_brave = True
    score = 0
    while feeling_brave:
        ghost_door = randint(1,3)
        print('Three doors ahead...')
        print('A ghost behind one.')
        print('which door do you open?')
        door = input('1,2 or 3')
        door_num = int(door)
        if door_num == ghost_door:
            print('GHOST!')
            feeling_brave = False
        if door_num > 3:
            print('GHOST!')
            feeling_brave = False
        else:
            print('No Ghost')
            print('You enter the next room...')
            score = score + 1
    print('Run away!')
    print('GAME OVER YOU SCORED', score)
```

Comment: you probably meant `elif door_num > 3:`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `elif` instead of the second `if` here:

```
if door_num == ghost_door:
    print('GHOST!')
    feeling_brave = False
elif door_num > 3:
    print('GHOST!')
    feeling_brave = False
else:
    print('No Ghost')
    print('You enter the next room...')
    score = score + 1
```

otherwise `else` is executed *independently* of the first `if` test if `door_num` is not greater than 3.

`if` is a single statement, with optional `elif` and `else` blocks attached; Python will always execute at most *one* of the attached blocks (and `else` otherwise).

By using two *separate* `if` statements, the second `if` asks Python to execute one of two blocks; print `GHOST` when `door_num` is greater than 3, or increase the score, and do so *regardless* of what the first `if door_num == ghost_door` test outcome is.